# What is client object model SharePoint online ie office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, rest, csom

What is client object model SharePoint online ie office 365 ?

Comment: Before asking this question, can you do a simple search in internet  about the mentioned topic?

Answer (score 0):

Its one of the of the frameworks used for development in SharePoint 2013 [though it already existed in SP 2010 version ]  &  called Client-side object model (CSOM).
Using this framework, developers can perform CRUD Operations on list/document library etc. objects,manipulate other SharePoint objects using C#(managed client object model), JavaScript.
Have a look at the below links :

[Technet Blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fromthefield/archive/2013/10/25/getting-started-with-office-365-and-the-client-side-object-model-csom.aspx)

[Vesa Juvonen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2015/04/10/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-office-365.aspx)

[using CSOM](http://tomaszrabinski.pl/wordpress/2013/03/18/connecting-to-office-365-using-client-side-object-model-and-web-services/)

[Authentication in SPOline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/03/authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx)

[packtpub](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/working-client-object-model-microsoft-sharepoint)

[dotnetcurry](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/sharepoint/1028/sharepoint-apps-javascript-object-model-jsom)

[geekswithblogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/11/26/csom-client-side-object-model---whats-new-with-sharepoint.aspx)

There exists a ton of information on CSOM on Internet.